# How to prevent the set of a get variable?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have a question. Let me explain this with an example.
I have this piece of code:

```
<form action="vehicles.php" method="get">
   <span>Marca:
       <select name="brand">
           <option value="null" selected="selected"></option>
           <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
           <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
           <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
           <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
       </select>
   </span>
   <span>Modelo: 
       <select name="model">
           <option value="null" selected="selected"></option>
           <option value="206">206</option>
           <option value="Suran">Suran</option>
           <option value="Passat">Passat</option>
           <option value="Punto">Punto</option>
        </select>
   </span>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Is any way to prevent the assignment of those variables if the option selected is the "null" one?

If, for example, I select brand="Renault" and model="null" the url is

`http://mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=Renault&model=null`

but it should be

`http://mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=Renault`

I know how to unset the variables with "null" value after the form submission with PHP. Is any way to do it before the submission and after the variables are setted to "null".
I would like a cleaner url, free of "variable=null" results.

P/D: I don't have a native english speaking so feel free to edit my question. I wish you understand me.

Comment: You don't like this ugly url but you're ok with the url if it has values in those get vars? Aside that, you may want to add a value parameter to the options in your select. <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>

Comment: Right, I only want the get vars in the url if they have a value.

Comment: you could use javascript to unset the name attribute of all selects with a null or - value on submit

Comment: @Orangepill In wich moment must I do it? Because I tried it with PHP succesfully but the url still the same because the unset is after the pages load.

Comment: this would be done on the client side before the information gets submitted... here is some jquery code (untested) that might get you there. `$(form).on("submit", function(){$('select').filter(function(){ $(this).val() != "-"; }).each(function(){ $(this).removeProp("name")});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you might need javascript to achieve what you want.
Take a look at this code:

```
<form action="vehicles.php" id="carForm" method="GET">
   <span>Marca:
       <select name="brand" id="brand">
          <option value="none" selected>-</option>
          <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
          <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
          <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
          <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
       </select>
   </span>
   <span>Modelo: 
      <select name="model" id="model">
         <option value="none" selected="selected">-</option>
         <option value="206">206</option>
         <option value="Suran">Suran</option>
         <option value="Passat">Passat</option>
         <option value="Punto">Punto</option>
      </select>
   </span>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitFormFilter();" />
</form>
```

Javascript : code will be like this:

```
<script>
function submitFormFilter(){
   var myForm = document.getElementById("carForm");
   var carBrand = document.getElementById("brand");
   var carModel = document.getElementById("model");

   if(carBrand.value === "none" || null){
       carBrand.parentNode.removeChild(carBrand);
   }

   if(carModel.value === "none" || null){
       carModel.parentNode.removeChild(carModel);
   }

   myForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xzKP/1/

you can it try here.

Answer (score 2):

Include the `value` attribute of your `option` tags.

```
<option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
```

You should really do this for all of your options.

Comment: I thought that without a value attribute the value will be that in the inner. I'll edit the code.
Anyway, if I set value="" then the url will be almost the same-->(http://mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=&model=).
I don't want the variables brand and model in the url if they have a blank value.

Comment: Of course it will which is why they are set to "-". Now they are set to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use `$_GET` superglobal because of the url extension that it comes with try using `$_POST` instead. It will not have a url extension and it can still store values that you can later retrieve. Just be sure to change your `method` to equal `POST` instead of `GET`.

So the code for the form tag would change to:

```
<form action="vehicles.php" method="POST">
```

And you can later access it by (for example):

```
echo $_POST['brand'];
```

or

```
echo $_POST['model'];
```

as well, you probably want to add a value param to the values that you have in your `option` tag.

EDIT-
I've added this new section since you don't want to use POST even though I think you should.

You can stay with the `GET` method by doing this line of code:

```
<form action="vehicles.php" method="GET">
   <span>Marca:
       <select name="brand">
           <option value="none" selected>-</option>
           <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
           <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
           <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
           <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
       </select>
   </span>
   <span>Modelo: 
       <select name="model">
           <option value="none" selected>-</option>
           <option value="206">206</option>
           <option value="Suran">Suran</option>
           <option value="Passat">Passat</option>
           <option value="Punto">Punto</option>
        </select>
   </span>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I want the url extension, but only to show those variables that have a value not blank (eg. "-" or "").

Comment: check out my new answer please

Comment: I want to use GET, and I want an url without blank variables.
For example:
If I select brand=Volkswage and model="" the url should be:
mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=Volkswagen

Comment: if you use that line of code up there it will display the names. Now what if the person chooses blank for both, do you want the url to just show vehicles.php? or vehicles.php?brand=&model=

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value for the option tag of `<select>` :)

Comment: this is suitable for a comment, but not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You's missing set value for option tag. you should set the value for option tag in select tag. With the blank value, you can assign it to a special value like zero(0)

```
         <select name="model">
           <option value="0" selected>-</option>
           <option value="1">206</option>
           <option value="2">Suran</option>
           <option value="3">Passat</option>
           <option value="4">Punto</option>
        </select>
```

**EDIT:** 
Ok. I got your point. You can import jquery to your page and make a check by javascript before you submit, if the value of select box is blank. you can remove it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ready(function(){
   $("form").submit(function(){
      if($("select[name='model']").val() == "0") $("select[name='model']").remove();
       return true;
   });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but this don't fix my problem. If I select the first option the url will still have "model=-".

Comment: that's stranger. I make a simple demo and the url look like this vihicle?model=0 . Check that you already set value for the _blank option. <option value="0">-</option> . Or you can use POST instead

Comment: Sorry, you are right, "model=0". But it doesn't fix my problem.
I want to hide "variable=value" from the url if the value is a special value like "0" or "-".

Comment: You should use POST instead GET:  you can change the define of form like this **<form action="vehicles.php" method="POST">**

Comment: You don't understand me.
First, I **want** to use GET. I want to show the options selected in the url but only those that don't have a blank value.

For example, if I select brand=Volkswage and model="" the url should be: mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=Volkswagen and **not** mywebpage.com/vehicles.php?brand=Volkswage&model=